# Best Way to Perform Addition and Multiplication on Django Fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model 'Manifests' and a form 'CreateManifestForm'.  The user enters multiple lines of data in the CreateManifestForm and these are saved to the Manifest model (on a line by line basis, not using ajax or anything).

There are 3 fields of concern in the model and form - 'Cases', 'FOB', 'CNF'. Both FOB and CNF are dollar amounts, so I'll use one as an example.  How could I take the user entered FOB price, multiply it by cases and then store that number? Additionally, when the user enters another line, how could I do the same and then add that to the original number so I can get a total value.

MODELS.PY

```
class Manifests(models.Model):

    reference = models.ForeignKey(Orders)
    cases = models.IntegerField()
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Products, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    CNF = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    FOB = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):

    form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                order = Orders.objects.get(id=reference_id)
                instance.reference = order
            except Orders.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            instance.save()
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id)})
    reference = request.POST.get('reference')
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference)


    context = {
        'form': form,
        'reference_id': reference_id,
        'manifests' : manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

ADD_MANIFEST.HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="container">
    <form id="create_mani_form" method="POST">

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.reference" class="formlabels">Reference ID: </label><br>
          <!-- <input type="text" value="{{ reference_id }}">-->
           {{ form.reference }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.description" class="formlabels">Description: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.product_name}}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.cases" class="formlabels">Cases: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.cases }}
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <label for="form.count" class="formlabels">Count: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.count }}
          <br>
          <label for="form.count" class="formlabels">CNF: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.CNF }}
          <br>
          <label for="form.count" class="formlabels">Count: </label>
          <br>
          {{ form.FOB }}
        </div>
          <br>
          <br>


      <button type="submit" name="add_mani" style="border-color: #7395AE;">Add Line</button>
    </form>


    <br>
    <h4>Manifest</h4>

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <!--<table  id="manifest_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0"-->
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered manifest_table" cellspacing="0" style="width="100%">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:2%;"</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Ref ID</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Cases</th>
          <th style="width:60%;">Description</th>
          <th style="width:10%;">Count</th>
          <th style="width:10%">FOB</th>
          <th style="width:10%">CNF</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        {% for manifests in manifests %}

        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="{#}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ manifests.reference }}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.cases }}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.product_name}}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.count}}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.FOB}}</td>
          <td>{{ manifests.CNF}}</td>
        </tr>

        {% endfor %}

      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="{% url 'display_orders' %}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" align="right" style="color: #7395AE; border-color: #7395AE; background-color: #FFF;">Subit Manifest</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



{% endblock %}
```

I would like to see a read-only field or something of that nature (I guess in the template) which shows the total for this particular manifest the user is creating. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want this to update as the user fills in the table, you need Javascript.

Comment: @DanielRoseman even though there is a refresh each time the user adds a new line?

Comment: Well, no, in that case you can do it in the view. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman user enters, cases and CNF values.  I would like to create a field which will multiply these two values together to get a Total. Then when another line is added and the page refreshes, the cases and CNF value will be multiplied for that line and added to the previous total - so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the manifest objects with a computed field

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper

manifests = Manifests.objects.filter(
                reference=reference
            ).annotate(
                total=ExpressionWrapper(F('cases') * F('CNF'), output_field=DecimalField())
            )
```

Then in your template you can reference `manifest.total`.

Comment: Brad, thank you for the response - first I get a syntax error at 'total': ....but I'm not sure what's wrong with that.  Second, you recommend referencing this in the template as manifest.total, but since this query is being set = manifests wouldn't I just reference 'manifests' in the template?

Comment: Apologies for the syntax error, fixed that.
For the template, I had thought your loop was `{% for manifest in manifests %}`. Actually, I'm not sure if you will cause yourself problems with having the same variable name `manifests` twice like you do.